# Eliminate the need for a loop in a simple example

Tags: r, loops

I have a problem that I am currently solving using a loop, but something tells me that it is possible to do so without. The main reason that I think it is doable is that all the exogenous processes are known at time 0.

Basically, there are two balances, a and b, that get depleted over time. Say 1 starts at 800 and one starts at 200. Each period, there are two exogenous processes x and y. X depleted the balances a and b in proportion to their total balance. Y depletes y directly until it is 0 and then it depletes x.

For example, period 1: `x = 10`, and `y = 5`. End of period `a = 800 - .8 * 10 = 792, y = 200 - .2 * 10 - 5 =193`. The next period, the multipliers for x have changed. They will now be 792/985 for a and 193/995 for y.

Here is a very simple example using a loop:

```
data <- data.frame(start_a = NA, start_b = NA, proportion = NA, x = runif(10, 1, 50), y = runif(10, 1, 50), end_a = NA, end_b = NA)

for (i in 1:(nrow(data))){
    data$start_a[i] <- ifelse(i==1, 800, data$end_a[i-1])

    data$start_b[i] <- ifelse(i==1, 200, data$end_b[i-1])

    data$proportion[i] <- data$start_a[i]/(data$start_a[i] + data$start_b[i])

    data$end_a[i] <- data$start_a[i] - data$proportion[i]*data$x[i] -

    ifelse((data$start_b[i] - (1-data$proportion[i])*data$x[i])<= data$y[i], data$y[i] - data$start_b[i] - (1-data$proportion[i])*data$x[i], 0)

    data$end_b[i] <- data$start_b[i] - (1-data$proportion[i])*data$x[i] - min(data$y[i], data$start_b[i] - (1-data$proportion[i])*data$x[i])
}
```

Again, the full time history of x and y are known at the beginning, so I have a gut feeling the loop isn't needed.

Comment: Probably not. The value of data$end_ai[i] and data$end_b[i] are computed in one step of the loop and used in the next step. For vectorization all of the values must be known in at the start of the operation. Also, you should not be using `ifelse` inside a loop since it is vectorized, but instead `if(...) {...} else {...}`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a function that uses vectorization to get `a` and `b` according to your explanation:

```
fSeries <- function(a, b, x, y) {
  n1 <- b%/%y
  aOut <- seq(a + b, 0, -x - y)
  a1 <- c(a, a*cumprod(1 - x/aOut[1:n1]))
  b1 <- aOut[1:length(a1)] - a1
  idx <- match(TRUE, b1 < 0) - 1L
  bOut <- c(b1[1:idx], rep(0, length(aOut) - idx))
  aOut[1:idx] <- a1[1:idx]
  return(data.frame(a = aOut, b = bOut))
}

df <- fSeries(800, 200, 10, 5)
list(head = head(df), tail = tail(df))
#> $head
#>          a        b
#> 1 800.0000 200.0000
#> 2 792.0000 193.0000
#> 3 783.9594 186.0406
#> 4 775.8773 179.1227
#> 5 767.7530 172.2470
#> 6 759.5854 165.4146
#> 
#> $tail
#>     a b
#> 62 85 0
#> 63 70 0
#> 64 55 0
#> 65 40 0
#> 66 25 0
#> 67 10 0
```

Comment: This is amazing. Thank you so much - most people gave up because they saw an i-1 in my loop but this is really a math question, not a coding question and you nailed it. I made some adjustments to use a random process for x or y, rather than a constant

Answer (score 2):

adding onto @jblood94 answer to use random vectors for x and y

```
n1 <- length(cumsum(y)[cumsum(y) < b])
aOut <- c(a+b, a + b -cumsum(x+y), 0)
aOut <- aOut[aOut > 0]
a1 <- c(a, a*cumprod(1 - x[1:n1]/aOut[1:n1]))
b1 <- aOut[1:length(a1)] - a1
idx <- match(TRUE, b1 < 0) - 1L
bOut <- c(b1[1:idx], rep(0, length(aOut) - idx))
aOut[1:idx] <- a1[1:idx]
output = data.frame(a = aOut, b = bOut)
```